# TFS include only a specific change in a change set to a Label

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) which denotes .visualstudio.com and the question I would like to ask is how can I include only the change in a specific change set to a label?

For example, let's take file A which was labeled on label A when the file was on version 10 and the file A had multiple other revisions and now the file A version is 15. Due to a business requirement I need to include the changes I did in file A with version 15 to label A and not the changes are made in between version 10 ~ 14.

How it is possible to achieve above stated scenario with VSTS?

Comment: What is your end goal here? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielMann the labels are used to capture the code related to a release. for example when a UAT release then the code is labelled up to that specific point. but the above need is required when we do some changes related to UAT after the release in the source code would like to include that change in the file to the label

Comment: Build definitions can create labels. What's insufficient about having your build process label your source code?

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the response and appreciate of you can elaborate your comment more by providing some guidance on your suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are a snapshot of a set of files, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files). A label is not a collection of changesets, but file versions.

A label can only contain one version of each file so in essence changing your label *A* to contain version 15 of file *A* will replace the link to version 10. But version 15 of file *A* will still contain the changes between version 10 ~ 15.

Comment: what is the best way to store a snapshot of a specific set of files with the questioned functionality

Comment: You might be better of creating a branch and then only merge some changesets to that branch.

Comment: @HusniJabir You can track the changes directly by the specific changeset, why you want to introduce the label?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT labels are used to create the point of source code related to each releases. my question is how can i include only the change in to a label.

Comment: @HusniJabir It's not possible as Tore Østergaard mentioned above, the label is a snapshot of a set of files, it will contais all the previous changes till the lable time.